# Modifying Options Field in IPv4 Header in Python

Tags: python, sockets, raw-sockets, traceroute, setsockopt

I am writing a somewhat atypical traceroute application in python. I am interested in counting the number of hops a packet takes before reaching its destination. The trick is I am interested in only probing with a single outgoing packet. I believe I can make some modification to the IPv4 options field to accomplish this. [RFC 1393](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1393#section-2.1) discusses what I believe I want to implement.

The issue comes from the poorly documented `setsockopt` function that I am using to configure my outgoing socket to make the IPv4 headers the way I want them.

The best I could come up with is the  following:

```
outputsocket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_OPTIONS, \
    '\x82\x0A\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x34\x56\x78')
```

(The byte string comes from section 2.2 of [RFC 1393](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1393#section-2.1))

This, however, gives me `socket.error: [Errorno 22] Invalid argument`

What can I do to make this work? I appologize if my approach is messy, I am not entirely comforable with python or using raw sockets.

Comment: Hmm, the RFC 1393 Traceroute IP option has been officially deprecated by RFC 6814 with the comment *The Traceroute option
   is defined as Experimental; it was never widely deployed on the
   public Internet*. Are you sure you really want to implement that?

Comment: As far as I know it is the only way to trace without deploying multiple probes for each hop. Is this not correct?

Comment: The problem is that most of the routers do not implement RFC 1393, so how could you be confident in results, unless you work in a fully closed environment?